# How to pass parameters to batch file

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I have created an exe file in my .NET project which accepts few paramters. I also have created a batch file which runs this exe and passes parameters.

Here is batch file

```
SET runner-path=%~dp0
SET reporter=%~dp0NUMyReportGenerator.exe
SET results=%runner-path%\Results\

START %reporter% %runner-path%TestResult.xml %results%TestResult.html MyThirdParamteter
```

When the batch file runs it throws an error because I pass a third parameter called `MyThirdParamteter`

So my exe accepts 3 parameter.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update1**

it was actually issue with my exe program and thats why it was not working. I was setting one variable to args[3] but instead i should have used args[2] because it starts from index 0. So no more error.

Comment: how are you running batch file?

Comment: @viveknuna i am running batch file via powershell script

Comment: Try with quotation: `start "" "%reporter%" "%runner-path%TestResult.xml" "%results%TestResult.html MyThirdParamteter"` (the empty pair of `""` defines a window title as `start` could otherwise misinterpret a part of the rest as such)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%1`, `%2`, `%3` and so on to get the parameters passed to the batch file and then run the batch file from command prompt something like this.

```
test.bat a b c
```

Here `a`, `b`, `c` are the parameters.

Comment: can you change my current code to explain it better?

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter to start should be a title, your first parameter is the executable. See https://ss64.com/nt/start.html

Comment: can you tell exactly what i should change in my code?

Comment: Removing start would probably fix it